# In ggplot2, specify a confidence interval (95% CI) around geom_smooth (or any trend line) using existing CI variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

**Background:**

I have a `df` tracking someone's `weight` over time (not mine I swear):

```
df <- data.frame(weight = c(156.8, 170,  185,   199.0, 203,  208), 
                lower95 = c(151.2, 165,  181.6, 194.5, 202,  206.4), 
                upper95 = c(162.8, 175,  187.9, 203.7, 204,  211.9),
                year =    c(2010,  2014, 2017,  2019,  2020, 2021))
```

I'm trying to make a simple `geom_smooth` like Hadley's in R4DS, like this one:

```
data(mpg)
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))
```

I like this because it has a shaded area around the main trends like that represents a 95% confidence interval. (I'm not sure how this MPG example is pulling a CI from the MPG data -- I don't see an SE variable -- but it's mostly beside the point for this question. If anyone has a good answer, lmk!).

**Problem:**

As you can see in my dataset, I've got 2 columns, `lower95` and `upper95` that contain the CI for each observation. How can I employ those as `geom_smooth`'s shaded area? Or, if not `geom_smooth`, then any trend line?

**What I've tried:**

I'm fiddling with things like `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` but only getting errors:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(data = df$weight) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(ymin = df$lower95, ymax = df$upper95))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close with your last attempt, but you never specified `x` and `y`! You also shouldn't use `data$column` inside `aes()`, it expects unquoted column names only, and you should put the ribbon first so the line is on top. And you don't need to keep specifying `data = df` unless you're using different data frames in different layers. Give this a go:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = weight) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower95, ymax = upper95)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Gah, pretty novice errors eh? Did I mention I'm new to plotting things in R? :) Works great, thank you Gregor!

Comment: Also @gregor, is there any way to adjust the opacity of the `geom_ribbon` ? As it is, even with the color set to "lightgray", it still blocks out the gridded background of the plot.

Comment: You can adjust the opacity of any element with `alpha`. `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower95, ymax = upper95), alpha = 0.5)`